# Why won't different method of resolving collisions give the same results as orginal

Tags: javascript, typescript, geometry, collision

I have to have circle-circle collision and response in a Typescript/Javascipt project I am working on. If two circles collide, one should be pushed out of the other, and in the correct direction. I have a method to resolve collision that works perfectly, but uses a square root call, which is not ideal, because there will be thousands of objects at any time. To fix this I tried a new method, without the square root call, however this returns incorrect results (`console.log()`ing them shows that they give different outputs, and when used in the project it does not behave properly.

Here is the current (working, but slow due to the square root call) code:

```
resolveCollision(circle: Cricle){
  const diff = Vector2.sub(this.pos, circle.pos);
  diff.norm(); //normailze the difference vector
  diff.mult(this.rad + circle.rad); //multiply the unit difference vector by the sum of the radii
  this.pos.setFromVector(diff.add(circle.pos)); //set our position to the (fixed) difference value + the other circle's position
}
```

The comments do it well, but here is a brief explanation:
Both this method and the broken one work in about the same way: By calculating the difference between the centers of the two circles, you can get the direction that the circle needs to be pushed out of (think of drawing a line between the centers of the circle, then moving the circle that needs to move along that line) The distance between the two centers of the circles is the sum of the radii, so now we can see how this method works:

1. Get the difference between the centers of the two circles
2. Convert that difference vector into a unit vector (this is what uses a square root)
3. Multiply that unit vector into a vector with the correct length
4. Set our position to the other circle's position plus the new correct length vector

So now here is the broken method:

```
resolveCollision(circle: Cricle){
  const diff = Vector2.sub(this.pos, circle.pos);
  const ratio = (this.rad + circle.rad)*(this.rad + circle.rad) / diff.calcSqMag();  //get the ratio between the current distance vector's length and the correct length
  diff.mult(ratio); //multiply the difference vector by that ratio
  this.pos.setFromVector(diff.add(circle.pos)); //set our position to the (fixed) difference value + the other circle's position
}
```

Steps 1 and 4 are the same as before, but here is an explanation:

2. Find the ratio between the length of the current distance vector and
3. Multiply the difference vector by that ratio

However, this method is either off by a few pixels, or completely off the screen. Where did I screw up?

For compleateness, here is the Vector2 class:

```
export class Vector2{
    x: number;
    y: number;
    sqMag: number;
    mag: number;
    constructor(x: number, y: number){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    add(vector: Vector2){
        this.x += vector.x; 
        this.y += vector.y; 
        return this; 
    }

    sub(vector: Vector2){
        this.x -= vector.x;
        this.y -= vector.y;
        return this;
    }
    
    mult(num: number){
        this.x *= num;
        this.y *= num; 
        return this; 
    }

    div (num: number){
        this.x /= num;
        this.y /= num; 
        return this; 
    }

    static add(first: Vector2, second: Vector2){
        return new Vector2(first.x + second.x, first.y + second.y);
    }

    static sub(first: Vector2, second: Vector2){
        return new Vector2(first.x - second.x, first.y - second.y);
    }

    static mult(vector: Vector2, num: number){
        return new Vector2(vector.x * num, vector.y * num);
    }

    static div(vector: Vector2, num: number){
        return new Vector2(vector.x / num, vector.y / num);
    }

    calcMag (){
        this.sqMag = this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y;
       return  this.mag = Math.sqrt(this.sqMag);
    }

    calcSqMag(){
        return this.sqMag = this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y; 
    }



    static calcMag(vector: Vector2){
        vector.sqMag = vector.x * vector.x + vector.y + vector.y;
        return vector.mag = Math.sqrt(vector.mag);
    }

    static calcSqMag(vector: Vector2){
        vector.sqMag = vector.x * vector.x + vector.y + vector.y;
        return vector.sqMag;
    }



    norm(){
        this.calcMag(); 
        return this.div(this.mag); 
    }

    static norm(vector: Vector2){
        vector.calcMag();
        return vector.div(vector.mag);
    }


    setFromVector(vector: Vector2){
        this.x = vector.x;
        this.y = vector.y; 
        return this; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The ratio you are getting is squared and you are using it as it would be same value as in first solution so you have:

```
const ratio = (this.rad + circle.rad)*(this.rad + circle.rad) / diff.calcSqMag();
diff.mult(ratio);
```

if you modify this a little bit to read as follows:

```
const ratio = (this.rad + circle.rad) / diff.calcSqMag();
diff.mult((this.rad + circle.rad) * ratio);
```

you can further expand it:

```
const ratio = (this.rad + circle.rad) / diff.calcSqMag();
diff.mult(ratio); // this should be normalized
diff.mult(this.rad + circle.rad);
```

you see second line should be `norm` so as in your initial code but instead of `ratio` being equal

```
ratio = 1 / diff.calcMag() = 1 / Math.sqrt(diff.calcSqMag());
```

(1 as in after this operation diff should have normalized length so be equal 1)
you have

```
ratio = (this.rad + circle.rad) / diff.calcSqMag()
```

Which I can not see any way to make equal